# ı couldn't attach cloth to my ship

Tags: cloth-simulation

I did a ship that floats on the surface of the ocean, and I did use a plate that I shrinkwrap the surface of the ocean for the ship to follow the rotation and location of the ocean surface. For that reason I think the cloth I did attach to the ship, didn't follow the ship and I did all of that hook, vertex things how can I fix that?

Comment: Hello it's not clear what the cloth is for, could you please tell more and show some screenshots?

Comment: Do you just need to parent the cloth to the mast, or suchlike, as well as setting up the pin vertex group? (works for me)

Comment: robin Betts thanks it's working :)